# How to set body for the content type multipart/form-data; boundary=NewPart for MSOneNote API using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, onenote-api

Have to send REST API request to MSOneNote  create page via nodejs .
How can i set body of content type "multipart/form-data; boundary=NewPart"

Here is my request body sample

```
--NewPart
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Presentation"
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <title>Page from OneNote API console</title>
    <meta name="created" content="2014-03-17T09:00:00-08:00" /> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HTML sample block</h1>

    <h2>The basics</h2>
    <p>For the most part, try to keep the HTML simple, and be 
      sure to properly close all tags.</p>

</body>
</html>
--NewPart--
```

.

Could anyone pls help me out how to set body for REST  API request  through javascript code.I have tried by appending the parts to list

Answer (score 0):

For a JavaScript sample of how to use our API (specifically sending a multipart request) see our NodeJS sample:

https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleNodejs

Specifically this file:
https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleNodejs/blob/master/lib/create-examples.js